# SQL Order the rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is the following db structure i have, here the issue we are facing to order the rows based on the filed wise.

**Field** - table hold the field information ed, 2002,2015, Region 1 etc

**IndicatorData**- hold the row data

**datafield** - relationship with IndicatorData table... row can have multiple fields

```
/****** object:  table [dbo].[indicatordata] ******/ 
create table [dbo].[indicatordata](
    [id] [bigint] null,
    [value] [decimal](18, 2) null,
    [hopevalue] [decimal](18, 2) null,
    [indicatorid] [int] null,
    [datakind] [int] null
) on [primary]
go
insert [dbo].[indicatordata] ([id], [value], [hopevalue], [indicatorid], [datakind]) values (195045, cast(70.00 as decimal(18, 2)), cast(0.00 as decimal(18, 2)), 2032, 0)
insert [dbo].[indicatordata] ([id], [value], [hopevalue], [indicatorid], [datakind]) values (195046, cast(40.00 as decimal(18, 2)), cast(0.00 as decimal(18, 2)), 2032, 0)
insert [dbo].[indicatordata] ([id], [value], [hopevalue], [indicatorid], [datakind]) values (195047, cast(5.00 as decimal(18, 2)), cast(0.00 as decimal(18, 2)), 2032, 0)
insert [dbo].[indicatordata] ([id], [value], [hopevalue], [indicatorid], [datakind]) values (195048, cast(100.00 as decimal(18, 2)), cast(0.00 as decimal(18, 2)), 2032, 0)
insert [dbo].[indicatordata] ([id], [value], [hopevalue], [indicatorid], [datakind]) values (195049, cast(87.00 as decimal(18, 2)), cast(0.00 as decimal(18, 2)), 2032, 0)
insert [dbo].[indicatordata] ([id], [value], [hopevalue], [indicatorid], [datakind]) values (195050, cast(9.00 as decimal(18, 2)), cast(0.00 as decimal(18, 2)), 2032, 0)
/****** object:  table [dbo].[indicator]  ******/
go
create table [dbo].[indicator](
    [id] [int] null,
    [name] [varchar](50) null
) on [primary]
go
insert [dbo].[indicator] ([id], [name]) values (2032, n'test tile')
/****** object:  table [dbo].[field]    ******/
 go
create table [dbo].[field](
    [id] [int] null,
    [name] [varchar](255) null,
    [rank] [int] null,
    [parentid] [int] null
) on [primary]
go
insert [dbo].[field] ([id], [name], [rank], [parentid]) values (120, n'2006', 18, 57)
insert [dbo].[field] ([id], [name], [rank], [parentid]) values (63, n'2015', 17, 57)
insert [dbo].[field] ([id], [name], [rank], [parentid]) values (303, n'2007', 9, 57)
insert [dbo].[field] ([id], [name], [rank], [parentid]) values (168, n'2018', 20, 57)
insert [dbo].[field] ([id], [name], [rank], [parentid]) values (1463, n'region 1', 1, 1459)
insert [dbo].[field] ([id], [name], [rank], [parentid]) values (1461, n'region 2', 3, 1459)
insert [dbo].[field] ([id], [name], [rank], [parentid]) values (57, n'year', 0, 0)
insert [dbo].[field] ([id], [name], [rank], [parentid]) values (1459, n'region', 0, 0)
insert [dbo].[field] ([id], [name], [rank], [parentid]) values (315, n'2002', 1, 57)
insert [dbo].[field] ([id], [name], [rank], [parentid]) values (123, n'2017', 19, 57)
/****** object:  table [dbo].[datafields]     ******/
set ansi_nulls on
go
create table [dbo].[datafields](
    [dataid] [int] null,
    [fieldid] [int] null
) on [primary]
go
insert [dbo].[datafields] ([dataid], [fieldid]) values (195045, 120)
insert [dbo].[datafields] ([dataid], [fieldid]) values (195045, 1463)
insert [dbo].[datafields] ([dataid], [fieldid]) values (195046, 63)
insert [dbo].[datafields] ([dataid], [fieldid]) values (195046, 1461)
insert [dbo].[datafields] ([dataid], [fieldid]) values (195047, 303)
insert [dbo].[datafields] ([dataid], [fieldid]) values (195047, 1463)
insert [dbo].[datafields] ([dataid], [fieldid]) values (195048, 168)
insert [dbo].[datafields] ([dataid], [fieldid]) values (195048, 1463)
insert [dbo].[datafields] ([dataid], [fieldid]) values (195049, 315)
insert [dbo].[datafields] ([dataid], [fieldid]) values (195049, 1463)
insert [dbo].[datafields] ([dataid], [fieldid]) values (195050, 123)
insert [dbo].[datafields] ([dataid], [fieldid]) values (195050, 1463)
go
```

Here is the query that i have tried to archive it. but its fail

```
    select fieldid, groupedData.value as value, groupedData.hopeValue as hopeValue, 
groupedData.datakind, groupedData.id as id, FieldSelector.name,
 groupedData.rank
from DataFields FieldsToInsert
join (
select d.id id,min(d.datakind) as datakind, sum(rank) rank, min(value) value, min(hopeValue) hopeValue 
from indicatorData d join datafields df on d.id = df.dataid
  join field f  on df.fieldId=f.id  where indicatorId=2032 
group by d.id) groupedData on FieldsToInsert.dataid = groupedData.id 
join Field FieldSelector  on FieldSelector.id=FieldsToInsert.fieldId
order by  groupedData.rank asc, groupedData.id
```

Output we got it is 
[View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Agklt.jpg)

Expecting the output is
[View image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tIuc.jpg)

Comment: "but its fail" is not a problem description. Do you get an error? What is the Error?

Comment: You have `order by  groupedData.rank asc, groupedData.id` and your output is ordered based on that, looks correct. How is it that you want it to be ordered?

Comment: I have updated the post, that how the o/p need to get....

Comment: So in your edit, expected output is another order, but you have also removed the `rank` column. So what is it that you want to order it by? The year in the name field?

Comment: @DanielBarbarian rank is just a column.. its not mandatory... "The year in the name field? " "Yes is reference to field table".... Order should return based on the field table

Comment: Ok, so ordering it by rank will not help then. It is quite possible that this can be solved the way you want, but I don't know exactly how. The thing that strikes me a bit is that you have both years and regions in the same table. Could it help to split them up?

Comment: no cant.... we have table called "Indicatordata" its hold the row                eg   id = 195045 ,value =70 And we have table called "DataField" its based on the "Indicatordata", dataid = 195045, fieldid=120 and  dataid = 195045, fieldid=1463

Comment: I couldn't see any difference between the two screenshots except for the rank column (which is apparently not required)

Answer (score 0):

So the first thought that strikes me is "Is the data correct?" I ask because looking at the years and rank values it suggests that 2006 should maybe be 2016 or the rank for 2006 should be 8 instead of 18.

That aside, and assuming the data is correct, you need to associate the region with the appropriate year. You can do this by getting the parent name for the field record and including the fieldid and then self joining back to get the associated year for that fieldid region record as follows...

```
WITH GroupedData AS
(            SELECT   d.id id,
                      min(d.datakind) AS datakind,
                      sum(f.rank) rank,
                      min(d.value) value,
                      min(d.hopevalue) hopeValue
             FROM     indicatordata d
             JOIN     datafields df ON d.id = df.dataid
             JOIN     field f ON df.fieldid = f.id
             WHERE    d.indicatorid = 2032
             GROUP BY d.id
)
,  df_parentType AS 
(   SELECT df.dataid,
           df.fieldid,
           f.name,
           f.rank,
           f.parentid,
           fy.name AS parentname
    FROM dbo.datafields AS df
    JOIN field AS f ON df.fieldid = f.Id
    JOIN field AS fy ON f.parentId = fy.Id
)
, df_yearregionmatched AS
(   SELECT df.dataid,
           df.fieldid,
           df.name,
           df.rank,
           dfp.name AS yearname,
           CASE df.parentname WHEN 'year' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS datafieldtype
    FROM df_parentType AS df
    JOIN df_parentType AS dfp ON dfp.dataid = df.dataid AND dfp.parentname = 'year'
)
SELECT   GroupedData.id AS fieldid,
         GroupedData.value AS value,
         GroupedData.hopeValue AS hopeValue,
         GroupedData.datakind,
         GroupedData.id AS id,
         FieldSelector.name,
         GroupedData.rank,
         FieldSelector.yearname,
         FieldSelector.datafieldtype
FROM     GroupedData
JOIN     df_yearregionmatched FieldSelector ON GroupedData.id = FieldSelector.dataid
ORDER BY FieldSelector.yearname,
         FieldSelector.datafieldtype;
```

I have used CTEs to keep the code uncomplicated. The ordering then is simply by yearname and a generated value to put year before region.

Comment: Thanks for your reply..., The data is correct .  Why you are using "dfp.parentname = 'year'" this filed will be dynamic... Instead of year, 2morrow field will be change(This is similar like pivot table)... But output is correct... kindly advice me to solve without defining the "dfp.parentname = 'year'" how an we achive..

Comment: `parentname = 'year'` is the value of the entry that is the **parent** for the associated row in that table. You have to associate the region record to the year record, or the lower ordered record with the higher ordered record. If the data is going to be different then this will need to show the higher ordered record so that you can associate the two.

Comment: see right now, row value hold two field called "Year,Region".. 2morrow row value hold more than two or three fields depends upon the Indicator

Comment: Can you provide more complete examples? The solution was based on the data that you provided

Answer (score 0):

**@nickFry**
Check another with complex example with one more field...

```
     create table indicator(id int not null,name varchar(255) not null)
insert indicator (id, name) values (1, 'basic employee details')

create table fields(
id int not null,  
rank int,
name varchar(255) not null,
parentid int not null)

insert fields (id, rank, name, parentid) values (1, 0, 'year', 0)
insert fields (id, rank, name, parentid) values (2, 1, '2010', 1)
insert fields (id, rank, name, parentid) values (5, 2, '2011', 1)
insert fields (id, rank, name, parentid) values (6, 3, '2012', 1)
insert fields (id, rank, name, parentid) values (7, 4, '2013', 1)
insert fields (id, rank, name, parentid) values (8, 5, '2014', 1)

insert fields (id, rank, name, parentid) values (9, 0, 'nationality', 0)
insert fields (id, rank, name, parentid) values (10, 1, 'libya', 9)
insert fields (id, rank, name, parentid) values (11, 2, 'ukrine', 9)

insert fields (id, rank, name, parentid) values (12, 0, 'gender', 0)
insert fields (id, rank, name, parentid) values (13, 1, 'male', 12)
insert fields (id, rank, name, parentid) values (14, 2, 'fe male', 12)

insert fields (id, rank, name, parentid) values (15, 0, 'maritalstatus', 0)
insert fields (id, rank, name, parentid) values (16, 1, 'married', 15)
insert fields (id, rank, name, parentid) values (17, 2, 'unmarried', 15)
insert fields (id, rank, name, parentid) values (18, 3, 'divorced', 15)


create table indicatorfields(
indicatorid int not null,
fieldid int not null,rank int)

insert indicatorfields (indicatorid, fieldid,rank) values (1, 2,1)
insert indicatorfields (indicatorid, fieldid,rank) values (1, 5,1)
insert indicatorfields (indicatorid, fieldid,rank) values (1, 6,1)
insert indicatorfields (indicatorid, fieldid,rank) values (1, 7,1)
insert indicatorfields (indicatorid, fieldid,rank) values (1, 8,1)
insert indicatorfields (indicatorid, fieldid,rank) values (1, 10,3)
insert indicatorfields (indicatorid, fieldid,rank) values (1, 11,3)
insert indicatorfields (indicatorid, fieldid,rank) values (1, 16,2)
insert indicatorfields (indicatorid, fieldid,rank) values (1, 17,2)
insert indicatorfields (indicatorid, fieldid,rank) values (1, 18,2)


create table indicatordata(
dataid int not null,
value varchar(255) not null,
indicatorid int not null) 

insert indicatordata (dataid, value, indicatorid) values (1, '1015', 1)
insert indicatordata (dataid, value, indicatorid) values (2, '15', 1)
insert indicatordata (dataid, value, indicatorid) values (3, '12', 1)
insert indicatordata (dataid, value, indicatorid) values (4, '187', 1)
insert indicatordata (dataid, value, indicatorid) values (5, '50', 1)
insert indicatordata (dataid, value, indicatorid) values (6, '65', 1)

create table datafields(
    dataid int not null,
    fieldid int not null)

insert datafields (dataid, fieldid) values (1, 8)
insert datafields (dataid, fieldid) values (1, 10)
insert datafields (dataid, fieldid) values (1, 16)

insert datafields (dataid, fieldid) values (2, 6)
insert datafields (dataid, fieldid) values (2, 11)
insert datafields (dataid, fieldid) values (2, 17)

insert datafields (dataid, fieldid) values (3, 7)
insert datafields (dataid, fieldid) values (3, 11) 
insert datafields (dataid, fieldid) values (3, 17)

insert datafields (dataid, fieldid) values (4, 2)
insert datafields (dataid, fieldid) values (4, 11)
insert datafields (dataid, fieldid) values (4, 16)

insert datafields (dataid, fieldid) values (5, 8)
insert datafields (dataid, fieldid) values (5, 10)
insert datafields (dataid, fieldid) values (5, 18)

insert datafields (dataid, fieldid) values (6, 2)
insert datafields (dataid, fieldid) values (6, 10)
insert datafields (dataid, fieldid) values (6, 16)
```

We need to get rows based on the indicatorfield & fields table order by rank

See the attached image for
Actual Output

[image: View Images]

This is wat i am looking for
Expected OutPut

[image]

Comment: Yes, you still have year and you still want everything grouped within that year. You have changed tablenames and removed columns but that aside the query still works....you just need to add rank as the second `ORDER BY` value; you may also need to add something to the datafieldtype CASE statement if the Nationality and Marital Status need to be in a specific order

Comment: Sometimes, year field will be not there.. you want the example without year ? i can give.... Order should be done based on the indicatorfield, field... and Nationality and Marital Status are dynamic....

Comment: If you check the attached image output, you can see data is order by indicatorfield, field

Comment: Prasad, in the examples that you have given "year" is not a field it is a value. The way in which you have stated that you want the results ordered you must associate the child items to a common parent and then work back down. If you have generic tables, that can hold any type of data, with varying columns etc it is going to difficult to get a "one size fits all" query that will work with every sort of data in every scenario.

Comment: Prasad, see below for example with no reference to 'year' or any other physical value...

Answer (score 0):

@Prasad, solution without reference to any hardcoded data value...

```
WITH GroupedData AS
(            SELECT   d.dataid id,
                      --min(d.datakind) AS datakind,
                      sum(f.rank) rank,
                      min(d.value) value --,
                      --min(d.hopevalue) hopeValue
             FROM     indicatordata d
             JOIN     datafields df ON d.dataid = df.dataid
             JOIN     fields f ON df.fieldid = f.id
             WHERE    d.indicatorid = 1
             GROUP BY d.dataid
)
,  df_parentType AS 
(   SELECT df.dataid,
           df.fieldid,
           f.name,
           f.rank,
           f.parentid,
           fy.name AS parentname
    FROM dbo.datafields AS df
    JOIN fields AS f ON df.fieldid = f.Id
    JOIN fields AS fy ON f.parentId = fy.Id
)
, df_parentmatched AS
(   SELECT df.dataid,
           df.fieldid,
           df.name,
           df.rank,
           dfp.name AS parentname
    FROM df_parentType AS df
    JOIN df_parentType AS dfp ON dfp.dataid = df.dataid AND dfp.parentname = (SELECT DISTINCT parentname FROM df_parentType WHERE parentid = (SELECT min(dataid) FROM df_parentType))
)
SELECT   GroupedData.id AS datadid,
         GroupedData.value AS value,
         --GroupedData.hopeValue AS hopeValue,
         --GroupedData.datakind,
         FieldSelector.fieldid,
         FieldSelector.name,
         GroupedData.rank,
         FieldSelector.parentname
FROM     GroupedData
JOIN     df_parentmatched FieldSelector ON GroupedData.id = FieldSelector.dataid
ORDER BY FieldSelector.parentname,
         GroupedData.rank,
         FieldSelector.fieldid;
```

Comment: i have posted another example..since we are close to the output.. pls have a look into that...

Answer (score 0):

@nickFy
The one you provide is fine... With this complex example... expected order is not coming in the correct way

Here is another complex example without the year

```
insert indicator (id, name) values (2, 'testing employee details 2')


insert indicatorfields (indicatorid, fieldid,rank) values (2, 10,3)
insert indicatorfields (indicatorid, fieldid,rank) values (2, 11,3)

insert indicatorfields (indicatorid, fieldid,rank) values (2, 13,1)
insert indicatorfields (indicatorid, fieldid,rank) values (2, 14,1)

insert indicatorfields (indicatorid, fieldid,rank) values (2, 16,2)
insert indicatorfields (indicatorid, fieldid,rank) values (2, 17,2)
insert indicatorfields (indicatorid, fieldid,rank) values (2, 18,2)


insert indicatordata (dataid, value, indicatorid) values (7, '1015', 2)
insert indicatordata (dataid, value, indicatorid) values (8, '15', 2)
insert indicatordata (dataid, value, indicatorid) values (9, '12', 2)
insert indicatordata (dataid, value, indicatorid) values (10, '187', 2)
insert indicatordata (dataid, value, indicatorid) values (11, '50', 2)




insert datafields (dataid, fieldid) values (7, 11)
insert datafields (dataid, fieldid) values (7, 13)
insert datafields (dataid, fieldid) values (7, 16)

insert datafields (dataid, fieldid) values (8, 10)
insert datafields (dataid, fieldid) values (8, 13)
insert datafields (dataid, fieldid) values (8, 17)

insert datafields (dataid, fieldid) values (9, 10)
insert datafields (dataid, fieldid) values (9, 14) 
insert datafields (dataid, fieldid) values (9, 18)

insert datafields (dataid, fieldid) values (10, 11)
insert datafields (dataid, fieldid) values (10, 13)
insert datafields (dataid, fieldid) values (10, 16)

insert datafields (dataid, fieldid) values (11, 10)
insert datafields (dataid, fieldid) values (11, 14)
insert datafields (dataid, fieldid) values (11, 16)
```

**Acutal Output we got is **

```
select a.dataid,value,df.fieldid,name from indicatordata a INNER JOIN datafields df on a.dataid=df.dataid
INNER JOIN fields f ON df.fieldid=f.id INNER JOIN indicatorfields indFields ON indFields.fieldid=df.fieldid
where a.indicatorid=2 and indFields.indicatorid=2 order by a.dataid
```

[image]

We need to order the fields based on the **indicatorfield & field** table

Expected Output should be like this

[image]